# Loading Xml into DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My Xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Test1>
  <Product Name="Test1" Value="10">
    <Catagory>
      <CatagoryType Value="20">AAA</CatagoryType>
      <CatagoryType Value="22">BBB</CatagoryType>
      <CatagoryType Value="23">CCC</CatagoryType>
      <CatagoryType Value="25">DDD</CatagoryType>
    </Catagory>
    <Type>
      <TypeName Value="11">111</TypeName>
      <TypeName Value="12">222</TypeName>
      <TypeName Value="13">333</TypeName>
      <TypeName Value="14">444</TypeName>
    </Type>
    <Location>
      <Area Value="0">Inside</Area>
      <Area Value="1">OutSide</Area>
      <Area Value="2">NoWhere</Area>
    </Location>
  </Product>
  <Product Name="Test2" Value="10">
    <Catagory>
      <CatagoryType Value="20">EEE</CatagoryType>
      <CatagoryType Value="22">FFF</CatagoryType>
      <CatagoryType Value="23">GGG</CatagoryType>
      <CatagoryType Value="25">HHH</CatagoryType>
    </Catagory>
    <Type>
      <TypeName Value="11">555</TypeName>
      <TypeName Value="12">666</TypeName>
      <TypeName Value="13">777</TypeName>
      <TypeName Value="14">888</TypeName>
    </Type>
    <Location>
      <Area Value="0">Inside</Area>
      <Area Value="1">OutSide</Area>
      <Area Value="2">NoWhere</Area>
    </Location>
  </Product>
</Test1>
```

I am trying to make which you can select a Product in a drop down. Then based on the product, get a category in another dropdown. Then Type in another, and location in the last. I have been able to get the Products to show in a drop down. But not able to get the rest of the elements in based on the product.

My code to load products into a drop down:

```
XmlDataset.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("XmlFile1.xml"));

drpProducts.DataSource = XmlDataset.Tables["Product"];

drpProducts.DataTextField = "Name";
drpProducts.DataValueField = "Value";
drpProducts.DataBind();
```

I cannot figure the next steps. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, using `LINQ to XML`. The idea presented in the following steps:

1. First, load all product to `Product Dropdown`.
2. When the `Product Dropdown` is changed, get the new value and populate appropriate data to the rest dropdown.

Here is the code. I create a demo program using `Windows Application`. But it's not important, just focus on how I select and populate data.

First, declaration:

```
private XDocument _document;
```

Run this function when first load:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    // Load the document
    _document = XDocument.Load("Product.xml");

    // Get the root's children, here is the products
    IEnumerable<XElement> products = _document.Root.Elements();

    // Get product name
    var productNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var element in products)
    {
        productNames.Add(element.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }

    // Assign to the source
    ddlProduct.DataSource = productNames;
}
```

When product name change, load the appropriate category.

```
private void ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // New value
    string productName = ddlProduct.Text;

    // Ignore empty value, or your XPath would be wrong
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Build the XPath
    string xPath = string.Format("//Product[@Name='{0}']", productName);

    // Select product with that name
    XElement product = _document.XPathSelectElement(xPath);

    // Select the CategoryType
    IEnumerable<XElement> categories = product.Descendants("CatagoryType");

    // Get the name
    var categoryNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        categoryNames.Add(category.Value);
    }

    // Assign to source
    ddlCategory.DataSource = categoryNames;
}
```

To make the answer simple, I only populate `Category`. The others are the same.

If you want to know more about XPath syntax, look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp). And for more information about `LINQ to XML`, check this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564).

Comment: Great answer. Works perfectly

Comment: Thanks! Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in this way:-

```
XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("XmlFile1.xml");

//XmlNodeList node = xdoc.SelectSingleNodes("/Test1/Product/");

var node = document.SelectNodes("/Test1/Product");

foreach(XmlNode n in node )
{
ListItem l = new ListItem();
    l.Text = n.InnerXml.ToString();
    drpWerk.Items.Add(l);
}
drpProducts.DataBind();
```

Comment: Comes back with the error "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Answer (score 0):

XML contains 7 tables when inported to a DataSet
[image]

The column names in the table are shown here
[image]

The Value is in the TypeName Table.  I use the Watch item in VS to view the DataSet object.